# $\chi_A(\lambda)=\lambda^n -Tr(A)\lambda^{n-1}+...+(-1)^ndet(A) \implies \chi_{A^{-1}}? $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{F})$ and $\chi_A$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $A$. I want to calculate $\chi_{A^{-1}}$. I know that the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is of the form $$\chi_A(\lambda)=\lambda^n -Tr(A)\lambda^{n-1}+...+(-1)^ndet(A).$$
Using the form of $\chi_A$ how can i calculate $\chi_{A^{-1}}$?

Answer (score 0):

If $\chi_A( \lambda)=\lambda^n+a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+....+a_1 \lambda +a_0$, then by Cayley - Hamilton:

$0=A^n+a_{n-1}A^{n-1}+....+a_1 A +a_0I$.

If $A$ is invertible and if $B:=A^{-1}$, then we get , by multiplying from the left with B^n:

$0=I+a_{n-1}B+...+a_1B^{n-1}+a_0B^n$.

Since $A$ is invertible, we get $a_0 \ne 0$. Hence

$0=\frac{1}{a_0}I+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{0}}B+...+\frac{a_1}{a_0}B^{n-1}+B^n$.

Therfore

$\chi_B(\lambda)=\frac{1}{a_0}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{0}} \lambda+...+\frac{a_1}{a_0}\lambda^{n-1}+\lambda^n$.

Comment: while the answer is certainly correct, the reasoning is not. The fact that $0=\frac{1}{a_0}I+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{0}}B+...+\frac{a_1}{a_0}B^{n-1}+B^n$ doesn't imply that $\chi_B(\lambda)=\frac{1}{a_0}+\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_{0}} \lambda+...+\frac{a_1}{a_0}\lambda^{n-1}+\lambda^n$.